# Laravel 5.8 issue in controller trying to access array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to loop through an array in one of my controllers in Laravel app and then pass it through to view.

It is currently throwing error **"Trying to get property of non-object"** which tells me the array is returning as null?

In my controller below, I am trying to set an array as empty by default and then pass in values to that array before passing it to the view, like so:

**Recipe Controller**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $tags2 = array();
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
        }

        return view('recipes.edit')->with('recipe', $recipe)->with('tags', $tags2);
    }
```

and my view

```
           <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage"></small>
                    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                    <select name="tags[]" id="tagsList" class="select2-multi" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach($tags as $tag)
                             <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
            </fieldset>
```

The point of this is to update existing tags on a recipe (my recipes are the equivalent of posts on this application). Storing and displaying tags works fine, but the edit is where I am having trouble. Please let me know if you see something that I don't.

Comment: since your `$tags2` is an `array`, you cant access its properties as object notation. you need to use array notation in your blade file. `<option value="{{$tag['id']}}">{{$tag['name']}}</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
    $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('recipes.edit')->with('recipe', $recipe)->with('tags', $tags);
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($tags as $id => $name)
     <option value="{{$id}}">{{$name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That worked fantastic! Thank you. What is the "pluck" in the Tag::pluck() if you don't mind me asking??

Comment: search `pluck` word

Comment: `Retrieving A List Of Column Values`